# How to call a shared class member function in a subdirs project?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt subdirs project called `Project`.

```
# Project.pro
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    Project-core \
    Project-gui


Project-gui.depends = Project-core
```

`Project-gui` has to call a function from `Project-core`, so I linked the projects as was shown in the [website](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application):

> you can right-click your project in Qt Creator and select "Add Library...", choose "External library" and browse for your library file:

I did this but I chose "internal library" instead of "external library". Now I am able to include header files of `Project-core` in `Project-gui`, and I marked one of the classes as `Q_DECL_EXPORT`. I tried to call a (static) member function of this class. But now I when I want to compile the project, the compiler output is a long and complicated error message:

```
21:14:15: Running steps for project Project...
21:14:15: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
21:14:15: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" -j8
cd Project-core\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\Project\Alpha\Project\Project-core\Project-core.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" ) && C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-core'
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-core'
mingw32-make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-core'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-core'
cd Project-gui\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\5.12.1\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Users\Usr\Desktop\Project\Alpha\Project\Project-gui\Project-gui.pro -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug" ) && C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-gui'
C:/Qt/Qt5.12.1/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-gui'
mingw32-make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-gui'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Usr/Desktop/Project/Alpha/Project/Project-gui'
21:14:20: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.12.1\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
21:14:20: Elapsed time: 00:05.
```

The error disappears if I don't call the function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Q_DECL_EXPORT` (or `PROJECTCORESHARED_EXPORT`) to all the classes that method uses fixed the problem.